# FiddlerCore HTTPS and HTTP Live Capturing(Packet Structure)

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, https, datagridview

Recently I've been working on Pcap library for live capturing of HTTP which is available easily. Now I've shifted to FiddlerCore as it can easily decrypt HTTPS packets.

I can now capture both HTTP and HTTPS packets but problem i'm facing is with packets structure.**I want to show the packet number the Url, URL referrer, Time, IP address in datagridview** but fiddlercore packet structure show me like that in image [Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izlrT.png)

I actually want to show the packet in datagridview in following style pls check attached image 
[This is second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5NLe.png)

Below also the pcap code sample

```
 if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Http != null)
                        {

                            HttpDatagram http = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Http;


                            // if http is 
                            if (http != null && http.Header != null && http.IsRequest)
                            {

                            rtbTest.Invoke( new Action( ( ) => rtbTest.AppendText(count.ToString() + ": " + packet.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff") + " length:" + packet.Length) ) );

                            //rtbTest.AppendText(count.ToString() + ": " + packet.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff") + " length:" + packet.Length);
                            rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText("\r\n")));
                            //rtbTest.AppendText("\r\n");

                            PcapDotNet.Packets.Http.HttpRequestDatagram http2 = (HttpRequestDatagram)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Http;

                                URLClass urlclass = new URLClass();}
```

**Code is not complete as it is only for demo**

```
 try
        {
            foreach (var x in URLData)

            {
                dgvPacket.Invoke(new Action(() => { dgvPacket.Rows.Add(); ; }));


                dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = x.PktCount;

                // dgvPacket.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.dgvPacket.Rows.Add(); ; }));
                dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = x.PktTime.ToString();
                dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = x.SourceIP;
                dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = x.HttpMethod;
                if (x.ConnectionType == null)
                    //  rtbTest.AppendText("-\t");
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText("-\t")));
                else
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(x.ConnectionType + "\t")));
                //  rtbTest.AppendText(x.ConnectionType + "\t");

                this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value = x.ConnectionType;
                rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(x.HttpVersion + "\t")));
                // rtbTest.AppendText(x.HttpVersion + "\t");

                this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value = x.HttpVersion;

                rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(x.URLString + "\t")));
                // rtbTest.AppendText(x.URLString + "\t");

                this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value = x.URLString;
                if (x.URLReferer == null)
                    // rtbTest.AppendText("-\t");
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText("-\t")));

                else
                    //rtbTest.AppendText(x.URLReferer + "\t");
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(x.URLReferer + "\t")));

                this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[7].Value = x.URLReferer;



                if (x.ContentType == null)
                {
                    //rtbTest.AppendText(" -\t");
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(" -\t")));
                }
                else
                {
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(x.ContentType + "\t")));
                    // rtbTest.AppendText(x.ContentType + "\t");
                    this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[8].Value = x.ContentType;
                }

                if (x.HttpCookie == null)
                {
                    // rtbTest.AppendText(" -\t");
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(" -\t")));

                }
                else
                {
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(x.HttpCookie + "\t")));
                    // rtbTest.AppendText(x.HttpCookie + "\t");
                    this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[9].Value = x.HttpCookie;
                }

                if (x.UserAgent == null)
                {
                    rtbTest.AppendText(" -\t");
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(" -\t")));
                }
                else
                {
                    // rtbTest.AppendText(x.UserAgent + "\t");
                    rtbTest.Invoke(new Action(() => rtbTest.AppendText(x.UserAgent + "\t")));
                    this.dgvPacket.Rows[index].Cells[10].Value = x.UserAgent;
                    index++;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Remember asking for FiddlerCore Packet structure

Comment: Looks like you are getting text data and need to convert to a DataTable.  Can you post sample of text file.  I can easily write a converter to put into a DataTable.  Then just make the DGV DataSource the DataTable.

Comment: Sample of the text file will be my live captured packets as shown in fig 1

Comment: HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  TCP has maximum number of bytes around 1500 bytes.  So a HTTP response/request consists of one or more TCP messages.   It appears that some of the fields you need are from the lower layer TCP messages.  If you displayed both TCP and HTTP you can combine fields to get what you need.

Comment: Never post images, Always post the text so it can be copied and processed.

Comment: Yes you're right but i'm using built in library fiddlercore and i'm stuck with that let me post a code of fiddler

Comment: Following says to use NetCap : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705672/fiddlercore-how-to-handle-tcp-traffic

Comment: I only need to work with https and https not TCP

Comment: i've added the fiddlercore code for you check it

Comment: How do you get the packet number and the keep-alive?

Comment: In pcap code i've create a class for keep alive and packet number and then call them in function

Comment: So how do you do the in FiddlerCore?  It is really gotten from the lower level  TCP.

Comment: FiddlerCore provide built in function which is why i'm asking here if someone uses it can help me out

Comment: The link I provided says you can't.

Comment: FiddlerCore only work with HTTP and HTTPS it cannot handle TCP and i'm not working on TCP i'm only concerned with HTTP packets

Comment: How many times do I have to say the same thing.  The calls you were making with PCAP were getting TCP info.  FiddlerCore does not handle the TCP info.

Comment: Okay I understand is there anyother way? Or if pcap supports HTTPS capturing?

Comment: The link I provided said to use NetCat.  Never used it so I'm not sure.

Comment: yes thanks. I'll let you know if i find any good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FiddlerCore code**

```
string url = sess.fullUrl.ToLower();

        var extensions = CaptureConfiguration.ExtensionFilterExclusions;
        foreach (var ext in extensions)
        {
            if (url.Contains(ext))
                return;
        }

        var filters = CaptureConfiguration.UrlFilterExclusions;
        foreach (var urlFilter in filters)
        {
            if (url.Contains(urlFilter))
                return;
        }
        // }

        if (sess == null || sess.oRequest == null || sess.oRequest.headers == null)
            return;

        string headers = sess.oRequest.headers.ToString();
        var reqBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sess.RequestBody); string firstLine = sess.RequestMethod + " " + sess.fullUrl + " " + sess.oRequest.headers.HTTPVersion;


        int at = headers.IndexOf("\r\n");
        if (at < 0)
            return;
        headers = firstLine + "\r\n" + headers.Substring(at + 1);

        string output = headers + "\r\n" +
                        (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reqBody) ? reqBody + "\r\n" : string.Empty) +
                        Separator + "\r\n\r\n";

        // must marshal to UI thread
        BeginInvoke(new Action<string>((text) =>
       {
           txtCapture.AppendText(text);
           UpdateButtonStatus();
       }
        ), output);
```